# Using Corcel with Laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am attempting to use Corcel with Laravel and I am following the instructions that are on the Corcel git: https://github.com/jgrossi/corcel  But, am having issues.

I am pretty new to Laravel, so I am certain it's something I am doing, but this is a learning experience for me and looking for those who may be able to point me in the right direction.

The problem I am having is when I get to the portion where it says "So, now you can fetch database data:"

```
$posts = App\Post::all(); // using the 'wordpress' connection
$posts = Corcel\Post::all(); // using the 'default' Laravel connection
```

I've tried both of those, and get the errors each time.

```
Class 'myNameSpace\Http\Controllers\App\Post' not found
```

That is when I use the App\Post version.

```
Class 'Corcel\Post\Post' not found
```

That is when I use the Corcel\Post version.

I also have this in my controller and the Post model class:

```
use Corcel\Post as Corcel;
```

Is there something that I am missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Try these at the top: `use App\Post;`, `use Corcel;`, then call them with `$posts = Post::all();` and `$posts = Corcel\Post::all();`

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same issues using Laravel 5.4. However, I managed to sort it out. It is based on the posts being placed in the Controllers folder.

**app/Http/Controllers/Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// Usage $posts = Post::all(); // using the 'wordpress' connection

use Corcel\Model\Post as Corcel;

class Post extends Corcel
{
    protected $connection = 'wordpress';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've setup and configured corcel accordingly.

```
//This goes into your App\Post

namespace App;
    
use Corcel\Model\Post as Corcel;
     
class Post extends Corcel
{
  protected $connection = 'wordpress';
}

//You can now start to get what you need from the WordPress database  in you App\Http\Controllers\PostController like so.

$posts = Post::published()->take(10)->get();
return view('post')->with('post', $post);
```